# Mongo DB - How to use different name as key instead of property name

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations to store MongoDB document.

```
@Document(collection = "api_response")
public class ApiResponse {

    private String dealNumber; // deal_Number
    private String systemCode; // system_Code

}
ApiResponse response = new ApiResponse();
mongoOperations.save(response);
```

It is saved properly. I need to have different key instead of actual property name. 
Instead of dealNumber, it should be deal_Number as key.

Is it possible?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to change the mapping between the Java field names and the MongoDB field names.

Comment: Yes I want to change the MongoDB field Name from Java field name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the Spring-Data-Mongo [Field annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Field.html) to implement the desired mapping:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;
// ...

@Document(collection = "api_response")
public class ApiResponse {

    @Field("deal_Number")
    private String dealNumber; // deal_Number

    @Field("system_Code")
    private String systemCode; // system_Code

}
```